Unable to Subscribe to Facebook Page Webhook:
I'm trying to subscribe to a webhook for a Facebook Page using my Facebook App, but I'm encountering the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "AL8xntMekDRZFSc5PBI8ct8"
    }
}

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I added my Facebook account as a role (Admin) in the Facebook App through the    developer dashboard.
Logged into my Facebook account and successfully retrieved the Page Access Token.
Verified that I have full admin access to the Facebook Page.
However, when I try to subscribe to the webhook, I get the error above.

Other details:

Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) enabled for the page or my account.
My Facebook App is in development mode.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
